# Detect taps but also drags for cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView in which I've enabled the dragging of items. But I also need to be able to detect taps on the items.

To detect tapping, I simply use didSelectItemAtIndex

To detect dragging, I've added a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to the collectionView and find the cell from the location of that long press:

```
    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(OrganizeWidgetsViewController.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    longPressGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 0
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.01
    widgetCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

The problem is that I need dragging to occur instantly when the user's finger touches the screen and starts dragging. However, the low minimumPressDuration of my longPressGestrue (which is 0.01) prevents taps from being detected.

My longPressGesture get detected, but the tap usually does not. Is there a better way to detect both tapping and enable dragging of a cell?

Comment: increase the min duration, I as an User always expect that dragging will happen if I press for a lil longer time and usual tap takes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the **longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration** to 0, and then check how far away the user dragged from the origin of the tap.

If the drag's max distance away from the origin is greater than a certain amount, I recognize it as a drag. Else, it's a tap.

**Step 1:** Implement the longPressGesture to the collectionView:

```
    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    longPressGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 0
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
    myCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
```

**Step 2:** Declare two variables on the class to calculate the distance of the drag

```
var startPoint: CGPoint?
var maxDistance: CGFloat?
```

**Step 3** Write a function that will calculate the total distance away from the origin of the drag (we'll use this method in the next step)

```
func calculateDistance(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow((from.x - to.x),2) + pow((from.y - to.y),2))
}
```

**Step 4:** Handle the drag

```
func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch(gesture.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        startPoint = gesture.location(in: myCollectionView)
        maxDistance = 0
        guard let selectedIndexPath = myCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: myCollectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        myCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
        maxDistance = max(maxDistance!, calculateDistance(from: startPoint!, to: gesture.location(in: myCollectionView)))
        myCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
        if maxDistance! < CGFloat(10) {
            if let selectedIndexPath = myCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: myCollectionView)) {
                collectionView(myCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: selectedIndexPath)
            }
        }
        myCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()

    default:
        myCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

**Note:**
We call didSelectItemAtIndex on our collectionView from within step 4, so make sure whatever functionality you want to occur on a tap goes within there.